# jquery selectmenu not initializing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using `filamentgroup jquery selectmenu()`, I am calling it on the dynamically built `selectlist` and on the `selectlist` which is already built but options are addying dynamically like:

**First case**

```
        $("presentselectlist").selectmenu();      //present selectlist initialized

        $("presentselectlist").html("<option></option>.."); // addding options dynamically 

        $("presentselectlist").selectmenu();  // then reinitilaized, but not working this line
```

**second case**

```
        var newselectlist = $("<select ..."); // creating new selectlist dynamicallly

        $(newselectlist).selectmenu();      // then initialized it by selectmenu but not working
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to alter the options in a `selectmenu` you'll need to disable it, alter the `<select>` to your liking, destroy it, then recreate it.

```
$('select')
    .selectmenu()
    .selectmenu('disable')
    .append($('<option></option>').attr('value', 'Tiger').text('Tiger'))
    .selectmenu('destroy')
    .selectmenu();
```

**Live Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/kpMkw/1/

This is not ideal but it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I spent an entire weekend searching for solutions to this.  Found several posts, but none worked. No one seemed to mention that you need to "disable" the damn thing before appending new options.  Just minor syntax errors above (but you have them fixed in your jsfiddle).

Comment: Glad I could help.  I updated my post to fix the syntax issue, thanks.